# Installing Lcms2

Tags: 16.04, package-management

I am trying to install lcms2 from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lcms2/2.9-1. I downloaded the file, did

```
tar -zxvf lcms2-2.9.tar.gz
```

then

```
./configure
```

When i now type in "make", this error pops up

```
In file included from ../../utils/common/utils.h:41:0,
             from jpgicc.c:28:
../../include/lcms2.h:259:22: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 #       define FALSE 0
                  ^
Makefile:470: recipe for target 'jpgicc.o' failed
make[1]: *** [jpgicc.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/usr/Downloads/lcms2-2.9/utils/jpgicc'
Makefile:476: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 if that is needed. 
Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you got this directory?

Comment: Try and delete the file and download it agian, so you have a fresh file

Comment: Yes, i did that and it still didnt work

Answer (score 1):

> Lcms2-2.9, Ubuntu 16.04

`sudo apt install g++ libtiff5-dev zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev`

Please use the patches for lcms2-2.9 :

```
tar xvf lcms2-2.9.tar.gz
cd lcms2-2.9/
tar xvf lcms2_2.9-1.debian.tar.xz     (debian/patches/ , etc.)
```

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lcms2/lcms2_2.9-1.debian.tar.xz

```
patch -p1 < debian/patches/dont-write-uninitialized-memory-for-color-strings.patch
patch -p1 < debian/patches/prepare-for-libtoolizing.patch
./configure
make                    (no errors)
```

Comment: Hi, I did this but i keep getting the same error.  I downloaded the debian tar.xz, did cd lcms2-2.9/, then the patch steps. The patches executed fine but when i did make, i got the same error. Kindly help. The below is how the error code is  `#ifndef FALSE
#       define FALSE 0
#endif
#ifndef TRUE
#       define TRUE  1
#endif`

Comment: Delete lcms2-2.9/config.status ... and run `./configure` again. Then you should be able to run 'make'.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but i got the following error. 
"configure: error: cannot run /bin/bash ./config.sub "

Comment: Well, better get the original " lcms2-2.9.tar.gz" : https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/blfs/conglomeration/lcms2/ ... and start from scratch. Please don't forget the patches. ( I edited the previous comment  to config.status, sorry for typo ).

Comment: Thank you very much for giving it a try. But somehow, i am not able to install it and i am running into the same error.

Comment: ? Did you change the compiler? Or something else ?  ( **GCC 5.5 is buggy** ) Please do `$ gcc --version`. ... **Lcms2 version 2.6** : `sudo apt install liblcms2-dev` .... P.S.: Lcms compiles OK, also with no patches, any OS, any gcc : -4.7 ...  -7.3 .